# OleDbConnection - Not all information being passed

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, executenonquery

I am trying to pass some information to an Access Database, however I'm not sure if I am using `ExecuteNonQuery()` correctly. Here is the code I'm using:

```
public void WriteToDB(string connStr, string tblName)
    {
        string[] accounts = { "@ID", "@Date", "@Line Item", "@Ranking Item", "@Item Attribute", "@Current_Period_Ranking(b)" };

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand CmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("Insert into [{0}] ([ID], [Date], [Line Item], [Ranking Item], [Ranking]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",tblName),conn);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 1);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "6/20/2016");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Line Item", this.ItemName);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking Item", "Ranking");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking", this.Rank.GetLineItem(3));
        CmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 2);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "6/20/2016");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Line Item", this.ItemName);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking Item", "Price");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking", this.Price);
        CmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 3);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "6/20/2016");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Line Item", this.ItemName);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking Item", "Pounds");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking", this.Pounds);
        CmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 4);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "6/20/2016");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Line Item", this.ItemName);
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking Item", "Opportunity");
        CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranking", this.Opportunity);
        CmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

When I run this bit of code, the Access DB only shows the 1's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the same command, you have to clear out the parameters afterwards:

```
CmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
CmdSQL.Parameters.Clear();
CmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 4);
....
```

On a side note, dates should be dates in a database, not strings.  Your database looks questionable if you have a bunch of tables with this same structure.  Why not just one table and a field that distinguishes what type of row it is.  It would make your queries easier.  It's also very common and beneficial to put those disposable database objects in using blocks.

Comment: Also on the dates: It's an external DLL I'm writing that will be communicating with VBA, So I'll be passing the dates in as strings and then loading them in as dates. Just haven't done the legwork on that part yet. This was just making sure the load was working. Thanks for your help though!